# Android gradle error version (3.3.1) problem

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have old project and I upgrade gradle. Gradle latest version 3.3.1. Please help me. How to fix this error?

> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to
>   process
>   /Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/support-fragment-28.0.0.aar/68845f02634c30733176d6df0bd9a4c9/jars/classes.jar
>
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while
>   dexing.    com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation
>   failed to complete
>
> com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error:
>   Interface `android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer(classpath class)`
>   used as super class of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$2`.
>
> Interface `android.support.v4.app.FragmentContainer(classpath class)`
>   used as super class of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$2`.

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "az.test.app”
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation project(':librarypull')
    implementation project(':GigglePicker')
    implementation project(':ResideMenu')
    implementation project(':Imageload')
    implementation project(':TouchImageView')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these things as follws:-

- Update your Class path to version 3.3.1 in (build.gradle) Project.
- Update you minimum or greater than 4.10.1 .in gradle wrapper
- Also add maven and google as per required in your project

  This will help you.